# py: runningmax with double deque and rampup ok?

Tags: python, pandas, rolling-computation

I have implemented this runningMax class:

```py
class RunningMax():

    def __init__(self,window):
        self.window = window
        self.values = deque()
        self.maxima = deque()
        return

    def append(self,x):
        self.values.append(x)
        i = 0
        while (len(self.maxima) > 0) and (x > self.maxima[-1]) and (i < min(len(self.values),self.window)):
            # pop all values at back that are smaller than new value
            self.maxima.pop()
            i += 1
        self.maxima.append(x)
        return

    def pop(self):
        full = len(self.values) == self.window
        if self.maxima[0]==self.values[0] and full:
            # if a value is about to leave the sliding window, kick it from maxima
            max = self.maxima.popleft()
        else:
            max = self.maxima[0]
        if full:
            self.values.popleft()
        return max

def compute_max(a,window):
    rm = RunningMax(window)
    maxs = []
    for i,ai in enumerate(a):
        rm.append(ai)
        maxs.append(rm.pop())
    return maxs
```

The output of `compute_max(a,window)` compares exactly to:

```py
pd.Series(a).rolling(window,min_periods=1).max()
```

So, its implemented correctly. Just would like to ask if there is any potential for improvement here? Anything that could be written more optimally basically.

Thanks!

Comment: have you looked at `cummax` https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.cummax.html
Actually a sample dataframe with expected output will be helpful

Comment: hey sayan thanks for the reply. i actually already have validated that the running max from pandas and my class produce exactly the same output. so its not about the output. its just, whether, looking at the way i implemented it, there are any striking inefficiencies that maybe unnecessarily slow down the code.